# MongoDB Timestamp of last write operation?

Tags: mongodb, timestamp

I want to verify that several Mongo DBs that we have set up are actually used. I was therefore hoping to get the timestamp of last write operation. What I found so far:

- querying collections with timestamps. Problem: different query for different collection. Not all of them have timestamps. Lots of collections in lots of DBs.
- Oplog in general. For STANDALONE server won't work - unless I create oplog now, by making a standalone server run in replica set. Then perhaps I could just ping the oplog and get the data. It may be faster to have a JS script asking for last objects.
- The [mongooplog command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongooplog/). Intended for *replicating* changes (applying changes from A to B). I'd rather browse the oplog itself.
- Use ObjectID (it has timestamp up to one second precise). There's even step-by-step blog post [detailing how](http://www.kchodorow.com/blog/2011/12/20/querying-for-timestamps-using-objectids/).

Still, I wondered if there's a way to just query the db and get it to answer. Preferably per collection, but if I could get the answer just per DB, would be cool. That would allow me to just drop unused DBs. Is there something I could use?

Comment: "mongooplog command" link is broken but the question is worthy.

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
db.serverStatus()
```

in the output of this command you have number of operations:

```
"opcounters" : {
        "insert" : 1111,
        "query" : 532,
        "update" : 0,
        "delete" : 0,
        "getmore" : 4,
        "command" : 357
    },
```

number of connections:

```
"connections" : {
    "current" : 1,
    "available" : 2047
},
```

network utilization:

```
"network" : {
    "bytesIn" : 82202280,
    "bytesOut" : 24469137,
    "numRequests" : 1635
},
```

it's enough to simple monitoring

Comment: Hmmm... must say, I haven't taken this command into consideration. Status of the server is one, but while it's really good at simple monitoring, I don't think this can give me information on "how many days ago this was last used". Nevertheless, will take a closer look, thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: Definitely good option for simple monitoring, but also definitely can't tell me when last write operation took place. At least on Mongo 2.4.3 it can't.

Comment: Stumbled on this answer and ended up using it as quick hackish solution. I just run a simple thread which calls this method every 100ms and if the insert opcounter increased since last call, then I set a last_insert_time var to the current time.  This gives me roughly 1/10 second precision which is more than enough for my application.  This works well enough for me as my application is on same server as DB so I am not concerned about latency, but if someone has come up with a better solution, please share..